# Avoiding duplication in parameter name

Tags: java, jsp, parameters

Inside a POST in a *.jsp* file, I'd like to do something like this:

```
<input type="text" name="...">
```

And inside the servlet I'd like to do:

```
request.getParameter(...)
```

Now where should and how should I declare "..." so that I can avoid duplication and reuse the same String.

Should this go in an interface like this:

public interface SO {

```
String POST_PARAM = "userinput";
```

}

Or in a property file? Or ...?

In any case, how do I then access this from the *.jsp* and from the *.java* file?

Comment: web developer who writing jsp page shouldn't use Java code, so putting such constants values into Java code isn't good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define constants like `final String POST_PARAM = "userinput";` and then use them in markup: `<input type="text" name="<%=POST_PARAM%>">`.
Moving fields names to properties file does not sound as a beneficial unless you have reasons to do this.

To get parameter value from HTTP request caused by form submit say `request.getParameter(POST_PARAM)`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: +1 thanks... but where should I define that constant?  In an interface? In a servlet?  I've tried defining it in an interface but then I couldn't reference it from the .jsp: I tried *<%=Build.POST_PARAM%> but it didn't work.

Comment: @CedricMartin You are on the right way. I suspect it did not work because you did not import the Build interface inside JSP. You need to import the interface at the top in JSP just like you do in a normal Java class. <%@ page 
import="Build" %>

Comment: You can define it everywhere but since it is preferable to implement java code in java classes and avoid scriplets in JSP it is recommended to create separate interface/class/enum that defines all needed constants.

Comment: No, using <%=POST_PARAM%> are not good for this purpose. Why don't you use JavaBeans technology and standard actions like setProperty

Answer (score 0):

You might get the ... from a bean using EL. However, it is not usual for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use standard actions: [jsp:useBean](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/tags/11/syntaxref11.fm14.html), [jsp:setProperty](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/tags/syntaxref.fm13.html) and [JavaBean](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/) technology:

---

**Example:**

`A.jsp` should call HTTP POST to `B.jsp`. `B.jsp` should automatically map all fields and redirect to your servlet.

```
// model.MyBean.java
class MyBean {
   private int age;
   // getters&setters
}

// A.jsp:
<form method="POST" action="B.jsp">
   <input type="text" name="age">
</form>

// B.jsp
<jsp:useBean id="form" class="model.MyBean" scope="request" />
<jsp:setProperty name="form" property="*" />
<jsp:include page="/servletURL" />
```

---

Small description:

1. MyBean class will be created. This bean should has exactly the same
   fields name like name in your form: for `<input type="text"
   name="age">` in bean should exists `int age` field and getter/setter.
2. `jsp:setProperty` with wildcard map all values from form A.jsp into your bean automatically.
3. if you want to call your servlet you can simple include appropriate url. Then in the servlet you will have access to request attribute "form" which will has MyBean with entered values.

Comment: that's kinda very verbose. I could somehow agree with you but it's 2011 and you're really suggesting to use mutable objects?  Like, beans with setters? Nah. I'm leaning towards a more functional approach nowadays (and could end up ditching Java altogether btw ; )    I don't like mutable stuff. I think the very fact that beans forces you to have setters is completely broken and is a valid enough reason to ditch Java as a whole ;) I realize someone at Sun may have decided it was *"the one holy way to do it"* but same people also thought mutability was a good thing, which makes me think :)

Comment: yeah, we have 2011 it's mean we do not use scriptlet <% %> and expression <%= %> - EL expression your friend. I don't catch why we should not use mutable object in 2011 year.